# Can't get DDE to work

Tags: sas, dde

I'm trying to learn how to work with DDE. So,I wrote a dataset name TEST as input:

```
data test;
    do i = 1 to 5;
        do j = 1 to 5;
            do k = 1 to 5;
                output;
            end;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

This is the path for my Excel:

```
options noxwait noxsync;
x '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE14\excel.exe"';
```

Now,

I'm trying to send all data to Excel. But for some reason, all I'm trying to do is send the first line. I tried with looping - but didn't work.

```
    filename example1 dde 'excel|sheet1!r1c1:r1c3';

    data _null_;
      file example1;
      set test;
      put i j k;
    run;
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I add colors and other styles ? Thanks,Gal.

Comment: I would use ODS ExcelXP Tagset instead. See http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup/excelxp_demo.html for examples

Comment: DDE is considered 'old' technology. I like the solution developed here for exporting to Excel as well: http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/A_Poor/Rich_SAS_Users_Proc_Export

Comment: Yes I would also take Stig's advice and opt for ExcelXP tagsets if possible.  I've done lots of work in DDE and it's a *very* clunky, idiosyncratic, and limited technology.  Despite these flaws, it's still a better option (barely) than having macros in your excel workbooks which leads to distribution and security issues (and end-user confusion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the data issue, you need to tell SAS to write to a range large enough to contain your dataset. Try:

```
filename example1 dde 'excel|sheet1!r1c1:r125c3';

data _null_;
  file example1;
  set test;
  put i j k;
run;
```

Asking for general advice about styles and colours is probably a bit too broad for this site - see what you can find with a bit of googling first and then post if you have problems with a specific bit of code.